# How one malloc call for all rows work for 2D array?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know that we can achieve dynamic multi-dimensional arrays using pointers and there are many ways to do it, with single pointers and double pointers as well. But while exploring on this topic, came across this piece of code in which I am not able to understand the head and tail. Can anyone please explain me how the below piece of code works?

Also please explain,

1) Why it is necessary to allocate `r*sizeof(int*)` to `arr` when we are anyways going to allocate memory to `arr[i]` as `r*c*sizeof(int)`.
2) Why it is necessary to do `arr[i] = *arr+c*i`.

Since I am very new to this dynamic memory allocation and so much eager to dig little deeper, arised these questions. Sorry if it is basic but still I have no idea about it. 
Thanks,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int r=3, c=4;
    int **arr;
    int count = 0,i,j;

    arr  = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * r);
    arr[0] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * c * r);

    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
        arr[i] = (*arr + c * i);

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            arr[i][j] = ++count;  // OR *(*(arr+i)+j) = ++count

    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d, %p, %p\n", arr[i][j], &arr[i][j], arr[i]);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1, 21100, 21100
2, 21104, 21100
3, 21108, 21100
4, 2110c, 21100
5, 21110, 21110
6, 21114, 21110
7, 21118, 21110
8, 2111c, 21110
9, 21120, 21120
10, 21124, 21120
11, 21128, 21120
12, 2112c, 21120
```

Comment: It gets to be real fun when you collapse all that into a single memory allocation, rather than using 2.  You could also consider using a variable length array (VLA).

Comment: [Don't cast `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/5958455).

Comment: Yeah but I just wanted to know how this works @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Why shouldnt I..? It is the usual method isn't..? @iBug

Comment: @Preethi See the linked question.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Thanks a lot for the link. Once will go through this completely and then remove the cast too. @iBug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of allocating for each of the `r` pointers allocated in `arr`, only the first one is used to allocate memory for an `rxc` array. And rest of the pointers points to chunk of this memory.

Benefit can be that it is possible to use single `memset` to initialize the array. Freeing is much more easier (just free the first pointer's allocated memory).

`arr[i] = (*arr + c * i);` this is basically initializing the pointer `arr[i]` with the relevant section to which it should point to.

And from the start of the allocated memory where will that be?
There `arr[0]`,`arr[1]`..`arr[i-1]` pointers which points to their rows which contains `c` elements each. So `c` elements each for `i` pointers - `i*c` elements all together is being addressed already. So the next one to be pointed by `arr[i]` will `(*arr+c*i)`.

After OP edited the question:

OP asked why we need to do `arr  = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * r)` ?

I guess this picture explains a lot than words.

```
arr --> [0]  [1]  [2]   [3]  .....[r-2] [r-1]
         |    |    |     |           |    |
         V    |    |     |           |    |
        [0] <-+    |     |           |    |
        [1]        |     |           |    |
        [2]        |     |           |    |
        [3]        |     |           |    |
        [4]        |     |           |    |
         .         |     |           |    |
                   |     |           |    |
        [c-1]      |     |           |    |
        [c]   <----+     |           |    |
        [c+1]            |           |    |
        [c+2]            |           |    |
         .               |           |    |
         .               |           |    |
         .               |           |    |
        [2c]  <----------+           |    |
        [2c+1]                       |    |
        [2c+2]                       |    |
         .                           |    |
         .                           |    |
         .                           |    |
        [(r-2)*c] <------------------+    |
        [(r-2)*c+1]                       |
         .                                |
         .                                |
        [(r-2)*c+(c-1)]                   |
        [(r-1)*c]  <----------------------+
        [(r-1)*c+1]
        [(r-1)*c+2]
        [(r-1)*c+3]


        [(r-1)*c+(c-1)]~[rc-1]
```

Those first row explains `arr  = malloc(sizeof(int *) * r);`

You can see all allocated memory in the soingle column. Because that's what you did `arr[0] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * c * r);`

And then the links explain `arr[i] = (*arr + c * i);`.

Check the thing, the links point to `(*arr)` also in pic `[0]`

and `(*arr+c)` in pic `[c]` and `(*arr+2c)` in pic `[2c]`.

We need them because it is basically letting us get to the beginning of the correct address of the starting of each of the `r` rows.

The address are being calculated as offset from the beginning of the `*arr`.

If you didn't assign the addresses to `arr[i]` then you couldn't access the array like this `arr[row][col]` then you had to do `arr[0][row*c+col]` (You can see that image also says that thing).

Comment: I understood the concept with these answers. Thanks a lot. But it will be much easier for others to understand the whole concept if the below point is also explained. Why do we still need to do {(r * c * sizeof(int *))} when we have already allocated memory for row? please explain that also..

Comment: Check the code...it's `r*c*sizeof(int)`..you have to store the `r*c` elements ..for that you need memory. And that's what is being done.@Preethi I will add it to answer when I reach my machine.

Comment: Yeah, I now have one more query. Why do we need to allocate `r* sizeof(int*)` memory to `arr` when we anyways going to allocate `r*c*sizeof(int)` to arr[0]. I have failed to understand this concept. I request you to explain this too. Thanks.

Comment: You have to allocate the pointers if you want to use arr[i][j] addressing

Comment: Well the array has `r` rows. And you need to have `r` chunks which you will access. So those `r` chunks address must be stored somewhere. And that's what is being done here. Here that's why you have `r`  int pointers because there will be `r` rows. @Preethi

Comment: Thanks @coderredoc But why we again allocate `r*c*sizeof(int)` to arr[i] and why is it not enough to allocate only `c*sizeof(int)`. Sorry I am little confused and may be taking your time too. I tried understanding by myslf and failed. Please help.

Comment: Edited my question too. Please visit.

Comment: @Preethi.: Hope this helps

Comment: The site says not to comment thanks. Still, so many thanks. This answer saved a week's time of mine. Thanks. @coderredoc

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code allocates two memory areas

- `arr` able to contain `r` pointers to int
- `arr[0]` area, for `r * c` int
- `(*arr + c * i)` is same as `&arr[0][c*i]`

then each `r` (row) is assigned a pointer to a location in `arr[0]` spaced by `c` (column) int (to store `c` int)

```
for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    arr[i] = (*arr + c * i);
```

graphically (with `r` == 3, and `c` == 4), `P` pointer, `I` integer

```
   arr: 0:P 1:P 2:P
        |   |   |
        v   v   v
arr[0]: IIIIIIIIIIII
```

then it just treats the array as a `arr[row][col]`

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            arr[i][j] = ++count;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, arrays are stored in "row major" order in memory. That means in a two dimensional array elements in the same row are adjacent to I've another in memory, and so elements in the same column are spaced apart by the number of columns (i.e  the row width).

`*arr` gives you back a pointer to an int because it is dereferencing a pointer to a pointer to an int. Specifically it is the pointer pointed to by the name arr. That is the base  address of the array.

arr[i] is also a pointer to an int. Now remember what I said about row major. Where should i-th row pointer point?  The answer is,  at the base of the array (`*arr`) plus `i` times the number of columns (`c`). The loop that confuses you is merely making the others point at the right places so that implied pointer arithmetic works when it comes time to use `arr[r][c]` notation.

Voila.

Comment: isnt *arr dereference pointer to int ? @vicatcu. Sorry if I failed to understand the concept. please explain

Comment: * (int**) = int*